# how to set read only access for file using java

Tags: java, inputstream, file-handling

How to set read-only access for a file that's been created and written using java InputStream API.

Comment: not quite clear what you're asking but you can use `java.io.File.setReadOnly()` to set a file to readonly.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, it's good to check whether the file has been created or exists first and then set the read only flag.

```
    File file = new File("C:/path/file.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.setReadOnly();
    } else {
        System.out.println("File does not exists.");
    }
```

Comment: I'm try to your solution i was  tried to do  your solution but it can't  set read only for that file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
File file = new File("C:\\pathToYourFile\\yourFile.txt") //for example
file.setReadOnly();
```

or if you use just

```
File file = new File("C:\\pathToDirectory");
```

you can lock the whole folder to be read only, if the current user has permission to modify access in that folder

Comment: Thank for your answer, but my teacher said to me : " java can't intercede to operating system ", and we can intercede it through keyword " Native" in java . it mean we can use language C to write a method because language C can intercede with operation system . (ex : window,....). And i try to  learn how to do it, if you have an opinion , let's describe it :)

Answer (score 1):

Well their are two ways to do it.

The first would be: `myFile.setReadable(false);`. This make the file unreadable by all applications. The other way would be `myFile.setReadOnly();`.

Note that in order for you to read the file from your application you will need to clear the ready only flag. To clear it use `myFile.setReadable(true);`.

Another thing to note would be that setting this flag only stops SOME applications from reading it, a lot of editors allow you to clear the flag. This will not prevent the user from deleting or moving the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could create new file object like this with readOnly property:

```
File readOnlyFile= new File("C:/test.txt");
readOnlyFile.setReadOnly();
```