# How to set windows folder read-only property in Java?

Tags: java

It's easy in python, `os.chmod("F:\\123", stat.S_IREAD)`

But what is the equivalent code in Java?

`file.setReadOnly();` and `file.setWritable(false);`does not work.

Comment: Looking at this post, it should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32947505/679240
What are you trying, and what results are you getting?

Comment: @Haroldo_OK I want to use desktop.ini to create customized icon for folder. It seems on Windows, a folder need to have read-only property itself to display the customized icon.